# Developing "hello world" app in Zend Framework

Tags: php, zend-framework

I am developing a "hello world" app in Zend Framework using [this article](http://rhythmiclife.com/tutorials/introduction-to-zend-framework-hello-world).

I am getting this problem:

```
Warning: require_once(Zend/Loader/Autoloader.php) [function.require-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\wamp\www\helloworld\index.php on line 11

Fatal error: require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening required 'Zend/Loader/Autoloader.php' (include_path='C:\wamp\www\helloworld/library;.;C:\php5\pear') in C:\wamp\www\helloworld\index.php on line 11
```

where is this autoloader.php I have included the library folder.

If I comment the autoloader class lines and run than I got this error:

```
.;C:\php5\pear // this is my set_include_path();
Fatal error: Class 'Zend_Controller_Front' not found in C:\wamp\www\helloworld\index.php on line 17
```

What is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

done it by [this](http://rahuldeveloper.blogspot.com/2011/01/installing-zend-framework-on-wamp.html)

Answer (score 1):

You do not appear to have set the `set_include_path()` correctly to point to the base directory, where the Zend library is located. Just unzipping the framweork from the .zip file (downloaded from the [Zend Framework](http://framework.zend.com/download/latest) site) isn't enough, the library dir you need is in a sub-directory of that.

Comment: okay ,i have puted the library as subdirectroy , but where is this zend/loader/autoloader.php is ? and why zend_controller_front is not found.